# Pipe 'translate' could not be found Ionic 4

Tags: pipe, ionic4, translate

I'm making a mobile's app where the language can be changed with Ionic4. I basicly followed this tutorial:  https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-multi-language-translation-feature-in-ionic-application-using-ngx-translate/.

And I'm getting this error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("

[ERROR ->]  {{ 'text' | translate }}
    Default"): ng:///ConfigurePageModule/ConfigurePage.html@16:2

I've been reading other posts where others had a similar problem but still couldn't fix it.

my app.module.ts

```
    import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
    import { TranslateConfigService } from './translate-config.service';

    export function LanguageLoader(http: HttpClient) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
    }
    @NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
entryComponents: [],
imports: [
    BrowserModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), IonicRatingModule, IonicSelectableModule, IonicStorageModule.forRoot(), 
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (LanguageLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
        ],
        providers: [
    StatusBar, Firebase, PhotoViewer, HTTP, Toast,
    AngularFireDatabase,
    CallNumber,
    EmailComposer,
    AngularFireAuth, AngularFirestore,
    SplashScreen, InAppBrowser, TranslateConfigService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    SocialSharing,
    File
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

my translate-config.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

    @Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
    })
export class TranslateConfigService {

constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService
) { }

getDefaultLanguage() {
    let language = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
    this.translate.setDefaultLang(language);
    return language;
}

setLanguage(setLang) {
    this.translate.use(setLang);
}
```

}

my configure.page.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ThemeService } from '../theme.service';
    import { TranslateConfigService } from '../translate-config.service';
    import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-configure',
      templateUrl: './configure.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./configure.page.scss'],
            })
    @NgModule({

    imports: [TranslateModule]
    })
    export class ConfigurePage implements OnInit {
selectedLanguage: string;
constructor(private theme: ThemeService, private translateConfigService: TranslateConfigService) {
    this.selectedLanguage = this.translateConfigService.getDefaultLanguage();
}


      ngOnInit() {
      }
        languageChanged() {
    this.translateConfigService.setLanguage(this.selectedLanguage);
    console.log(this.selectedLanguage);
        }
    }
```

my configure.page.html

```
    <ion-content>
{{ 'text' | translate }}
<div style="padding:10px;">
    <h5 style="">Configure sus preferencias</h5>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Select Language</ion-label>
            <ion-select placeholder="Select One" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" (ionChange)="languageChanged()">
                <ion-select-option value="es">Español</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="en">English</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
    </ion-content>
```

my en.json
        {"title": "Ionic 4 Multi Language Translation","text": "This is random text to show translation in application"
            }
my es.json
        {"title": "Esta en ESpañoool", "text": "Texto aleatorio"}

The json files are in assets/i18n, but I didn't had that folder so I created manually. Could be this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing you putting it into the page level module file as well.

If you look at [Simon's tutorial for this](https://ionicacademy.com/localise-ionic-ngx-translate/) on Ionic Academy you will see there is an extra section under "Using ngx translate Service, Pipe and Directive".

For your project you would need to open up `configure.module.ts` and add the `TranslateModule` something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ConfigurePage } from './home.page';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({</ul>


  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: ConfigurePage
      }
    ]),
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [ConfigurePage]
})
export class ConfigurePageModule {}
```

I'm seeing a possible variation of this as the [first comment](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-multi-language-translation-feature-in-ionic-application-using-ngx-translate/#comments) at the bottom of JollyFreaky's tutorial as well, so if that doesn't work try importing it like:

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: ConfigurePage
      }
    ]),
    TranslateModule.forChild()
  // etc
```

Comment: I tried your solutions and still get the same problem. Also I followed the tutorial https://ionicacademy.com/localise-ionic-ngx-translate/ , same result. Could be because I created the folder i18n manually?

Comment: no, the folder is nothing special, I don't see how that could be the issue, even if you made it in the wrong place, as its complaining about the pipe not existing. I think that you must have another issue. Have you used the translate pipe in more than one page? -- it needs adding to every page like that uses it in the way I described above.

Comment: no, I only use it in the Configure page (it will be implemented in evry page, but for startting just that page)

Comment: and you're still seeing that error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("`

Comment: At this point it feels like there is a small mistake somewhere rather than something major missing. I would try following the tutorial on a standalone new test app just to be totally sure that it does work. And then compare each step to the real project. Is your app accessible via a repo or anything that we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing too, I'd suggest that adding the following minimum in the module code of your ts page.

```
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

then,

```
imports: [ 
    TranslateModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the solution works if the source have each page specific mouldes. You must add the pipe module to each page specific modules to get it work.

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { RegisterOnePage } from "./register-one";
 import { PipesModule } from '../../../pipes/pipes.module';

 @NgModule({
  declarations: [RegisterPage],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(RegisterPage),
    PipesModule
  ]
})
export class RegisterPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/ng2-translate/#lazy-loading-pages

## Lazy loading pages

If you want to use Ionics lazy loading pages together with ngx-translate, you have to configure your ***component.module.ts*** files.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';//<- add this
import { HelloPage } from './hello-page';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HelloPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HelloPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild()//<- and this
  ],
  exports: [
    HelloPage
  ]
})
export class HelloPageModule {}
```